# HTML Radio Buttons: add space between the buttons from the same groupe

Tags: html, radio-button

I have 3 radio buttons on the same line in a td of the table like that:

```
<td align="left">
            CHF <input type="radio" name="currency"  id="chf_currency" checked="checked" onChange="currencyChanged()" />
            USD <input type="radio" name="currency" id="usd_currency" onChange="currencyChanged()"/>
            EUR <input type="radio" name="currency" onChange="currencyChanged()"/>
</td>
```

Now I would like to add some spaces between those radio buttons and I don't know how to do it.

I tryed to use width attribute, margin attribute but nothing changes.

Thank you very much.

Comment: use `input[type="radio"]{padding: or margin or line-height}`

Comment: Hi @ArpitSrivastava, Thank you for your answer. The line you give me is CSS ? I am new in HTML and WEB programming, sorry for asking that.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Check working example [on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ofoguk/1/edit)

Also, here is the code:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <td align="left">
            CHF <input type="radio" name="currency"  id="chf_currency" checked="checked" onChange="currencyChanged()" />
            USD <input type="radio" name="currency" id="usd_currency" onChange="currencyChanged()"/>
            EUR <input type="radio" name="currency" onChange="currencyChanged()"/>
</td>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
input[type="radio"]{
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use like this in CSS

```
input[type="radio"]{
      //padding: or margin or line-height for better spaces bettween radio button according to your need and design;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

> input[type="radio"]{margin:10px 0};}

put this in the css folder or in the header section of your html file. If your putting this in your html file in your header section, it should look like this:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
   input[type="radio"]{margin: 10px 0};} 
</style>
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use fixed `padding` to the buttons, then consider wrapping each one with `<label>` tag, this will make the labels clickable too.

HTML:

```
<label>CHF <input type="radio" name="currency"  id="chf_currency" checked="checked" onChange="currencyChanged()" /></label>
<label>USD <input type="radio" name="currency" id="usd_currency" onChange="currencyChanged()"/></label>
<label>EUR <input type="radio" name="currency" id="eur_currency" onChange="currencyChanged()"/></label>
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
label + label {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9cJJ9/